# Repast: start the simulation from negative tick

Tags: repast-simphony

I am modeling a delivery system and the delivery schedule time is more than one day 24hr. A part of the scheduled time is arranged in the prior day which is shown as a negative number. For instance, -300 means the delivery task to be arranged at 19:00pm on Day-0. 300 means another delivery arranged at 5:00 am on Day-1.

In ideal way, I hope the simulation to be carried out in this form:

```
@ScheduledMethod(start = -300, interval = 1, priority = 4)
```

So that I don't have to do any number conversion which will bring a great mess in relation to a lot of schedules.

I tested but it appears that the schedule method needs to start from at least "tick 0". Any solution to this?

Comment: A simple way I could think is to create a custom tick counter to correspond to the repast tick counter. For instance, if the business operations starts from 19:00pm in D-0 to 8:00am in D-2. Then the Repast tick counter is scheduled as [0, 1920+300], the customer tick counter is scheduled as [-300, 1920]. All my task schedules will be referring to the custom tick counter during the simulation. I am still interested to know if the default tick counter can be customized?